# AJAX request with nested objects to Spring MVC controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC web-application. I want to use Hibernate and AJAX.
There are two entities: Item and CatalogItem. Entity CatalogItem contains some fields and reference to Item.

It is possible using AJAX to create CatalogItem? With plain objects i have no problems, but with nested.. I want something like this:
POST-request from jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': myurl,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'data': JSON.stringify({'count':10,'deliveryTime':'2012-12-12T12:12:12',
    'itemId':{'name':'name','price':100,'description':'qwerty'}}),
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': function(){
        //
    }
});
```

In spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addItem(@RequestBody CatalogItem catalogItem) {
    catalogDAO.addCatalogItem(catalogItem);
}
```

But this does not work. It throws

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: entities.CatalogItem.itemId] with root cause
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: entities.CatalogItem.itemId
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You are trying to save a CatalogItem without first saving an Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to save a CatalogItem without first saving an Item.

Without seeing your mappings it's hard to say otherwise.

Read the Hibernate docs on [cascading](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade).